# Gmail gadget's "RecipientToEmailExtractor" doesn't return all recipients email addresses

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have a Gmail contextual gadget app that uses some of the Google-offered content extractors.

I have noticed that the "google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor" recently only returns one email address even if the email has multiple recipients. It used to work properly for me a while back, returning multiple addresses separated with ";".

Did anybody else encounter this problem? Is this a Google bug?

Answer (score 0):

I too am using the **google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor** extractor and when I have multiple emails in the **to:** field, I get multiple matches. ie. The result of the following call

```
google.contentmatch.getContentMatches()
```

Returns and array of the same length as their are emails in the **to:** field. Each member of the array is a js object with a key name of **recipient_to_email** and a value of the actual email.

The fact that you mentioned it used to return all addresses separated by a **;** character suggests something may have changed